# How to deal with URL arguments in Django REST Frameworks

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django REST Frameworks and despite doing the tutorial twice and reading lots of documentation I can't work out exactly how to handle/access the arguments in a URL in the DRF ViewSet.

My URL looks like this:

```js
/api/v1/user/<user-id>/<age>/update
```

In my base urls.py I have the urlpattern:

```js
url(r'^api/v1/', include('api.urls'))
```

In the api/urls.py I have:

```js
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from api import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'user', views.UserViewSet) 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

My question is what should my UserViewSet look like to handle the url, extract the user id and age fields, and update the UserDetails model so the given user has the given age?

My model hasn't been created yet but will look something like this:

```js
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    age = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: could you include the code in `api.urls`?

Comment: Do you have to use this URL pattern? It would be more idiomatic to send PUT or PATCH requests to `/api/v1/user/<user-id>` with `{"age": 42}` in the request body. Then you'd [override update or partial_update](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) in your ViewSet. Those methods receive the user id as the `pk` keyword argement.

Comment: Unfortunately that is the style of url I have to implement to tie in with existing appd

Comment: Can you go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350762/composite-keys-in-django-rest-framework/32494272#32494272 will help you

Comment: I am still struggling, despite the link supplied, to work out how to do this. I am hoping some kind person will show me a code snippet for my user case.

Answer (score 2):

In the serializers.py adde the [ParameterisedHyperlinkedIdentityField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362142/django-rest-framework-hyperlinkedidentityfield-with-multiple-lookup-args/31161585#comment52334331_31161585) as a serializer.

## serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = ParameterisedHyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='user-detail', lookup_fields=(('id', 'id'), ('age', 'age')), read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserDetails
```

## urls.py

```
from .viewsets import UserViewSet
user_list = UserViewSet.as_view({'get':'list'})
user_detail = UserViewSet.as_view({'get':'retrieve'})

urlpatterns= [
    url(r'^user/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<age>[-\w\d]+)/update/$', user_detail, name='user-detail')

]
```

## viewsets.py

```
class UserViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = UserDetails.objects.all()
```