# How to use data of vue object in django Templates href

Tags: django, vue.js

I want to construct an url using django templates href mode, but the problem is that the url must contain data from vue object.
In my Vue object, I use **${}** to avoid delimiter clash with django, so I try to construct url like this:

```
{%url 'main:commodityInfoPage' %{task.category} %{task.searchKey} %}
```

Whole code of this part like this:

```
<tr v-for="task in taskList">
    <td>${task.searchKey}</td>
    <td>${task.category}</td>
    <td>${task.taskId}</td>
    <td>${task.status}</td>
    <td><a href="{%url 'main:commodityInfoPage' %{task.category} %{task.searchKey} %}">Info</a></td>
</tr>
```

And my django router like this:

```
path('commodityInfo/<str:category>/<str:searchKey>/',views.commodityInfoPage, name = 'commodityInfoPage')
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Now I know it is about the params **%{task.category}**,**%{task.searchKey}**. But I don't know how to set the format correctly, could you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Why don't you write vue.js or Vuejs+Vuex as a standalone frontend app and the make API call to django backend for communications. The best standard is to keep frontend 100% seperated from the backend All your backend responses from django should be in json and then let  vuejs do the rendering and other things.

Comment: @NancyMooree My initial thought is literally writing a standalone fronted app, it seems that I misunderstand how to do it. Is it Vuex serve as a similar role like django template href by storing the prefix url?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362142/django-rest-framework-hyperlinkedidentityfield-with-multiple-lookup-args/31161585#comment52334331_31161585 and the formed url in vuejs rendering